# How to set title on Seaborn JointPlot?

Tags: python, seaborn

The `JointPlot` documentation does not show the title : can it be set?

http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html?highlight=reg

[image]

Comment: why would this method be excluded?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

this worked for me

```
p = sns.jointplot(x = 'x_', y = 'y_', data = df, kind="kde")
p.fig.suptitle("Your title here")
p.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)
p.fig.tight_layout()
p.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.95) # Reduce plot to make room
```

Comment: Alternatively, just `plt.suptitle("Your title here")`.

Comment: @RomeoValentin that didn't work as an Attribute Error of `'JointGrid' object has no attribute 'suptitle'` is thrown. In order to fix it, you need to add `plt.fig.suptitle("Your title here")`

Comment: additionally the ._set_alpha(0) can be misleading